# ComponentWillUnmount equivalent with React Hooks that has access to the current values of state variables?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a functional component with hooks, that calls a function **only once when it gets unmounted**. In this function I need to access the components **current state variables**.

[This codesandbox illustrates the core problem I'm facing](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-satoshi-z60zx)

I know that I could pass the state variable in the useEffect dependency array, but in my real world example it is a requirement that the effect is only called once when the component unmounts, and adding it to the array would cause it to be called on every render.

Also I tried useCallback, useRef to the state variable and searched for similar use cases and examples without success and I feel like that I'm missing something.

Is there a way fulfil both requirements (only is called once and access to current state variables)?

Also here is my code of my example. The button mounts/unmounts the counter and what I'd like to achieve is, that the last value of the counter is printed when it disappears.

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // this should print the counters current value
      console.log("Count was " + count + " when counter disappeard!");
    };
  }, []); // Empty because effect should only run when component unmounts

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{count}</button>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [showCounter, setShowCounter] = useState(true);

  // mount/unmount the counter
  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowCounter(!showCounter);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Show/Hide counter</button>
      {showCounter && <Counter />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would be really glad if someone knows a way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution would be to save the state in a ref and have a seperate useEffect hook which updates the ref when the state changes. Then you can access the "last" state via the ref object.

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-diffie-8tiev

Comment: Exactly what I needed. This way, the logic stays self contained in my component. That was one thing I wanted to achieve. Thank you. 

It would be interesting what the React Team suggest in this case though.

Answer (score 1):

This could work :

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-leaf-jmdu1

i don't know if that's the solution you're looking for

Comment: Technically in this example: yes. But that would mean that everytime I wan't to use the counter component I would have to maintain this piece of state outside the counter. This is something that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: But maybe I could wrap the counter into another component that is just responsible for that piece of state . I will try that and let you know if that worked.

Comment: So basically this approach is a possible solution, but it requires a kind of complex work around in my real world example. Thank you for your input.